# Producer Consumer Thread with shutdown c++

Tags: c++, producer-consumer

Hi quick question given the following c++11 code which works fine for producer/consumer, the problem is I want to shut the DataQueue down and stop all consumers. Although there in lies the issue as the problem is the consumers just call popWait() and can be blocked.  How can I shutdown my consumers in this case? This is probably a design issue that needs to be rectified. I am trying not to incur any performance hits as this code should ideally be using a disruptor pattern or similar to make the queue lock free. Being that as it may I was wondering if there was something simple to have the consumers know to stop calling the pop wait function when the producer shuts down. The tricky part is shutting down if there is still data on the queue you would have to wait to have the consumers finish pulling off the data. I believe I have a solution where the consumer has it's own shutdown but open to ideas. Thanks in advance.

```
#ifndef __DataQueue_h__
#define __DataQueue_h__

#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>

template <typename DataT>
class DataQueue
{
  public:

  DataQueue (): _shutdown(false), _waitTime(5), _itemAvailable() {}

  void push ( const DataT& data )       
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
    queue.push(data);
    _itemAvailable.notify_one();
  }

// worked fine until I need to shutdown services... then some were blocked
  DataT popWait()
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);

    if(queue.empty())
    {
      _itemAvailable.wait(lock);
    }

    DataT temp(queue.front());
    queue.pop();

    return temp;
  }

  inline void shutdown()
  {
    _shutdown = true;
  }

  private:
  std::queue<DataT> queue;
  bool _shutdown;
  unsigned int _waitTime;
  std::mutex _mutex;
  std::condition_variable _itemAvailable;

};

#endif
```

Comment: wait waits to be notified... notify_one notifies one... notify_all notifies all waiters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea would be to wake up all consumers in the call to `shutdown`<sup>1</sup>. In the `popWait` method, you could then check if the shutdown flag was set as you return from `wait`.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>

template <typename DataT>
class DataQueue
{
public:
    DataQueue (): _shutdown(false), _itemAvailable() {}

    void push ( const DataT& data )       
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        queue.push(data);
        _itemAvailable.notify_one();
    }

    Maybe<DataT> popWait()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);

        while(queue.empty() && !_shutdown)
        {
          _itemAvailable.wait(lock);
        }

        Maybe<DataT> data;
        // leave pending data in the queue
        if (_shutdown) 
        {
            // consumers should stop polling when receiving an 'empty' value
            return data;
        }

        data.add(queue.front());
        queue.pop();   
        return data;
    }

    inline void shutdown()
    {
        _shutdown = true;
        _itemAvailable.notify_all();
    }

private:
    std::queue<DataT> queue;
    std::atomic<bool> _shutdown;
    std::mutex _mutex;
    std::condition_variable _itemAvailable;
};
```

**Return value of popWait**

Apart from all the synchronization and signalling stuff, you also have to reconsider the return value of `popWait`. If you want to implement a generic `shutdown()` method, i.e. without stuffing special sentinel values into the queue itself, the `popWait` has to be able to return a 'value' that indicates that the producer has stopped - maybe something templaty like `Maybe<DataT>`<sup>2</sup>. I envision that `Maybe<DataT>` could either return `DataT` or nothing in which case the consumer would stop polling.

```
template<typename DataT>
class Maybe 
{
   DataT _data;
   bool _empty;

pulic:
   Maybe() : _data(), _empty(true) {};

   void add(const DataT& raData)
   {
      _data=raData;
      _empty=false;
   }

   bool isEmpty() const
   {
      return _empty;
   }

   DataT get() const
   {
      return _data;
   }
}
```

This is a rather primitive interface. You could extend it as necessary.

<sup>1</sup> [ComicSansMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577603/comicsansms) pointed out to me that I should be declaring `_shutdown` member variable as `std::atmic<bool>` to avoid memory reordering issues. Thanks for the heads-up.

<sup>2</sup>I just stumbled over [`std::optional<T>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++14#Optional_values) (new in C++14), which essentially what I had in mind.

Comment: `_shutdown` should be an `atomic<bool>` in this case or you will risk nasty memory ordering bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You can push a "poison pill" object into the queue. In fact, push as many as the number of consumers that you want to shut down. This way, you will also get rid of the shutdown member variable to be checked offloading this check to the receiving thread, which is increasing overall queueing performance.

This is the approach I did for my thread pool implementation and it works perfectly.

Comment: And how do you determine the number of consumers without introducing a race? This approach is fine if you know the number of consumers beforehand (as you do for a thread-pool), but won't work otherwise. You could try to re-push the poison pills after a thread has detected the shutdown condition, but that can also easily lead to subtle races. A global shutdown flag is definitely easier to pull off.

Comment: You can push another poison pill object for shutdown. In that case you push in one object and the receiver pushes it back before shutting down. Note that in any case, as long as you don't know the exact number of consumers, it will be difficult to find out, if all consumers are shut down.

Answer (score 0):

In `popWait` you could check if the queue is empty OR `_shutDown` is true. In the latter case you notify the caller that he should no longer ask for data (throw an exception (not optimal in my opinion), or redesign the method signature a bit). Then all you have to do is have a `notifyAll()` call in your `shutdown()` method.